# Why yii captcha always shows a fixed picture?

Tags: javascript, php, validation, yii, captcha

Captcha works with no problem, but I have no idea why it's not generating a new code to dislay? I've looked into the documents but could find something that could solve my problem.

[image: captcha image]

Is there something here that I'm missing. thanks.

```
public function actions()
    {
        return array(
            'captcha'=>array(
                'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
                'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
            ),
        );
    }
```

my view file:

```
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'verifyCode'); ?>  
        <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
```

Comment: @SamuelLiew, I don't think It has anything to do with session as It doesn't change at all. If I come back tomorrow and test it again I would see the same thing.

Comment: If I reduce session timeout. it would be public. How to just fix this specific problem. short session timeout would kick my users out early!

Comment: I was wrong about the global sessions timeout value, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, that would most likely be fixed in Yii2.

---

On the Yii forums, user *Black* [suggests](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/17638-captcha-code-not-changing/page__view__findpost__p__164975):

> My solution was to remove the session key on my controller action on get. Be careful not to remove it in any other place because it will probably fail on server validation.

```
$session = Yii::app()->session;
$prefixLen = strlen(CCaptchaAction::SESSION_VAR_PREFIX);
foreach($session->keys as $key)
{
        if(strncmp(CCaptchaAction::SESSION_VAR_PREFIX, $key, $prefixLen) == 0)
                $session->remove($key);
}
```

---

Another way to workaround would be to [use JavaScript to click on the refresh link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6180387/584192) on every page load as mentioned by *Soph*:

```
$(function() { 
    $('#yw0_button').click(); 
});
```